# How do I get rid of Windows stopped responding with 100 % disk usage?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, freeze

I'm using Windows 10 with Ubuntu GNOME duel boot on Dell laptop. I sometimes (sometimes often) face the issue of Windows stopped responding and when I run taskmanager, found 100% disk usage. Earlier I solved this problem by disabling windows search permanently. However again I started to face the issue after a month. (Let me inform that I've not installed any hardware or driver).

I've found many articles discussing the issue which provides some methods to solve the problem. I've not gone through that all except disabling windows search. (Also note that I first always apply disk checking `chkdsk /f` when I face the issue which doesn't solve the problem).

Usually the disk usage reach at 100% just after startup and login i.e without opening any application/software that can consume the disk usage. I also set most of startup apps disables.

So, I want to know what can cause for using 100% disk usage and How do I get rid of it? Since the issue recently cause for breaking the startup of windows ultimately! see [my next question...](https://superuser.com/q/1271426/328353)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try disabling the Superfetch service if you are using an HDD.

Push Windows + R, type `services.msc` and Superfetch can be disabled from there.

When I was installing Windows 10 on a few brand new laptops, I experienced similar issues, and this helped alleviate the disk usage problem. This may not be applicable if you are using an SSD.

I have heard the BITS service may also cause disk usage problems, but I am not sure on this.

Comment: Yeah, I've just remeber of `net.exe force stop superfetch` didn't work.

Comment: Have you disabled it completely so it doesn’t start up again upon restart?
May be worth trying BITS too.